# Magento: Changing datatype of database column in a custom module beeing ignored

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I wrote my own Module in Magento (1.7.0.2) that works with it's own database table. The database table was created via an install script within the module, simply executing a

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [...]
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

I made a mistake in one column, declaring the wrong datatype on it ( `int(11)` instead of `decimal (11,4)` ) resulting in a value of "10.10" getting stored as "10".

Now when I change the datatype of this column either via phpmyadmin or via update script the datatype gets changed perfectly in my table, still Magento saves the values as the old datatype, resulting in a value of "10.10" getting stored as "10.0000".

When I enter a value of "10.10" via phpmyadmin it gets stored correctly. But when i try to add that value via

```
Mage::getModel('mymodule/mymodel')->setMyAttribute("10.10")->save();
```

it still ends up as a "10.0000" in the database.

I've had this problem before and was only able to fix it by adding a new column with the correct datatype on creation of that column.

It seems like Magento has some sort of cashing mechanism for custom table's datatypes, which i can't seem to find anywhere in the database.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a DDL cache issue. Have you already tried to clear `var/cache/*` folders?

Comment: Jürgen, that did the trick. Had'nt thought of that, thanks a lot!